# How do i match Layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers

am trying to create a map, which shall show NRW ( a part of Germany) with some extra gimmiks. Those Gimmiks are Coordinate based locations of several Manufacturers. Later on i want to adjust the background color to statistik Data.

The Base map is Ready.

Now i tried to add the Locations of the manufacturers. Therefore i created a Textdata with the coordinates. via layers/Add Layers / Import Textdata as Layer (I have a german version so it is free translated)i tried to add this Layer. After several tries it worked 
The Problem is now, that this Layer is not overlapping with the Card i have so far created. I think it has something to do with the reference Coordinate System but i dont know how to correct it.

Can somebody pls help me?

Comment: What Base map do you use, and are the coordinates in degrees or meters?

Answer (score 1):

Create the xy event layer using the Add Delimited Text layer tool.  Once you have the point data loaded define the CRS as whatever the point coordinates are in (e.g. EPSG:4326 - WGS 84), then export out the event layer to a actual GIS point layer (e.g. Shapefile or something else).  Finally, make sure your Project>Project Properties>CRS setting for Enable "on the fly" CRS transformation is checked.  This will allow your map to reproject data that is in different projections so all your layers overlay property (as long as all your layers have their CRS defined properly).